# How to use useMemo instead of a local state using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

i want to use useMemo instead of a local state using javascript, react and graphql.

what i am trying to do?

I am displaying a progress bar based on data fetched from progress query. the fetched data from progress query is set in a state.

below is the code,

```
const ProgressModal = (status) => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState<>(undefined); //progress state 
    //setting
    
    const { data: progressData, stopPolling: stopPolling } = 
        useCheckProgressQuery({
            variables: {id},
            pollInterval: 3000,
        })
   
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (status === initial) {
            setProgress(undefined);
        }
        if (status===started) {
            setProgress(progressData);
        }
        if (status === finished && completed >= total || status === failed) {
            stopPolling();
            setProgress(undefined);
        }
    }, [progress, progressData, setProgress]);

    const completed= progress
        ? progress.Progress.completed : 0;
    const total = progress ? progress.Progress.total : 0;
    let value = 0; 
    if (completed > 0 && total > 0) {
        value = (completed / total) * 100;
    }

    return (
        <ProgressBar value = {progress} />
    );
}
```

the above code works but how can i use useMemo for above case instead of a local state. could someone help me with this. i am new to using react hooks. thanks.

Comment: This isn't what useMemo is for. It's for caching. Use useState, or useReducer, or useRef for state

Comment: It makes no sense to replace state with `useMemo` here. You would essentially be trying to recreate a state functionality with a memoized value that constantly changes. You essentially want to store a value, and re-render the progress bar whenever that value changes. That's exactly what state is for. Do some Googling and have a look at examples and use cases for `useMemo`, might help you get an idea of when it can/needs to be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useMemo` and `useState` with `useEffect` do different things, so you can not convert `useState/useEffect` 100 % equally to `useMemo`.

A more or less equivalent `useMemo` approach would be this (but it doesn't work, other refactoring would then also be necessary, see below):

```
const progress = useMemo(() =>{
  if( status === initial ){
    return undefined;
  }
  if( status===started ){
    return progressData;
  }
  if( status === finished && completed >= total || status === failed ){
     return undefined);
  }
  return undefined; // <-- you need to define default/fallback
},
[ progressData, status, completed, total ] // <-- some where missing in your example
);
```

This is not a working solution, more refactoring is required:

- Here e.g. `stopPolling()` is not called, which needs an extra `useEffect` now.
- `progress` depends on `completed` and `total`, and `completed` / `total` both depend on `progress` (circular dependencies)